# Expand one sub menu others should automatically hide in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to make expandable accordion menu with CSS and JQuery, i want to make a vertical accordion menu and hide sub-menus when i click on other main links, can some one please help me to do this.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/e22dvkyr/)

```js
$(function() {
  
 $('.submenu-class li').has('.mainmenu-submenu, .mainmenu-submenu-sub, .mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub').prepend('<em class="mainmenu-click"><i class="arrowupdown"></i></em>');
 
 $('.submenu-class li').has('.megamenu').prepend('<em class="mainmenu-click"><i class="arrowupdown"></i></em>');
  
 $('.mainmenu-mobile').click(function(){
  $('.submenu-class').slideToggle('slow');
 });
 $('.mainmenu-click').click(function(){
 $(this).siblings('.mainmenu-submenu').slideToggle('slow');
 $(this).children('.mainmenu-arrow').toggleClass('mainmenu-rotate');
 $(this).siblings('.mainmenu-submenu-sub').slideToggle('slow');
 $(this).siblings('.mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub').slideToggle('slow');
 $(this).siblings('.megamenu').slideToggle('slow');
  
 });

});
```

```css
 
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{content: ""; display: table;}.clearfix:after{clear: both;}.clearfix{zoom: 1;}.cl{clear: both;}
ul, ol{margin-top:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;  margin-bottom:0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    box-sizing: border-box; padding:0px ; list-style:none;}
 
.submenu-class li a{
 display:block;
 background-color:#fff;
 color:#424242;
 padding:0px 14px; line-height:48px;
 border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
 text-decoration:none;}
  
 
.mainmenu-click {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 display:block;
 cursor:pointer;
 width:100%;
 }

.mainmenu-click i{
 float:right;
 display:block;
 height:23px;
 width:25px;
 margin-top:11px;
 margin-right:8px;
 background-size:25px;
 font-size:21px;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 
 }

 
.mainmenu-submenu-sub{
 width:100% ;
 position:static ;
 left:100% ;
 top:0 ;
 display:none;
 margin:0px ;
 padding:0px ;
 border:solid 0px ;
 transform:none ;
 opacity:1 ;
 visibility:visible ;
 }
 
.mainmenu-submenu-sub li{
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px ;
 padding:0px;
 position:relative;}
 
.mainmenu-submenu-sub a{
 display:block;
 padding:10px 25px 10px 25px;
 border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
 font-weight:normal;}
 
 

.mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub{
 width:100% ;
 position:static ;
 left:100% ;
 top:0 ;
 display:none;
 margin:0px ;
 padding:0px ;
 border:solid 0px ;
 transform:none ;
 opacity:1 ;
 visibility:visible ;
 }
 
.mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub li{
 margin:0px 0px 0px 0px ;}
 
.mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub a{
 display:block;
 color:#000;
 padding:10px 25px;
 background:#000 ;
 border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;
 font-weight:normal;}
 
 
.mainmenu{position: relative;}

.arrowupdown{ width:9px; height:9px; background-color:#ccc; }
 
.mainmenu .submenu-class li{
 width:240px;
 display:block;
 float:none;
 border-right:none;
 background-color:transparent;
 position:relative;
 white-space:inherit;}
 
.mainmenu .submenu-class  li  a{
 padding:9px 32px 9px 17px;
 font-size:14px;
 text-align:left;
 border-right:solid 0px;
 background-color:transparent;
 color:#666666;
 line-height:25px;
 border-bottom:1px solid;
 border-bottom-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.13);}
 

.submenu-class .mainmenu-submenu{
 transform:none ;
 opacity:1 ;
 display:none;
 position:relative ;
 top:0px;
 background-color:#fff ;
 border:solid 1px #ccc;
 padding:0px;
 visibility:visible ;
 }
 
.submenu-class .mainmenu-submenu li a{
 line-height:20px;
 height:36x;
 background-color:#fff ;
 font-size:13px ;
 padding:8px 0px 8px 18px;
 color:#8E8E8E;}

.submenu-class .megamenu{
 background-color:#e7e7e7;
 color:#666666;
 display:none;
 position:relative ;
 top:0px;
 padding:0px;
 border:solid 0px;
 transform:none ;
 opacity:1 ;
 visibility:visible ;
 }
 
.submenu-class li:hover .megamenu{display:none; position:relative ; top:0px; }
.megamenu .title{ color:#666666; font-size:15px ; padding:10px 8px 10px 0px;}
.halfdiv .title{ padding-left:15px;}
.megamenu > ul{
 width:100% ;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-size:13px ;}
 
.megamenu ul li a{
 padding:9px 14px ;
 line-height:normal ;
 font-size:13px ;
 background-color:#e7e7e7 ;
 color:#666666;}

.mainmenu {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius:0px;
 z-index:100;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
 border:none ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainmenu clearfix">
  <ul class="submenu-class">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="hometext">Open Menu 01</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdowns  </a>
      <ul class="mainmenu-submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 01</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 01</a>
          <ul class="mainmenu-submenu-sub">
            <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 02</a>
              <ul class="mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub">
                <li class=""><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 03</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 03</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 03</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#">Dummy Sub menu style 03</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Open Page text Menu 01  </a>
      <div class="megamenu clearfix">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Open Page text Menu 01  </a>
      <div class="megamenu clearfix" > Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e22dvkyr/1/)

Modified your click function as below:

```
$('.mainmenu-click').click(function () {
    $('.mainmenu-submenu').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.mainmenu-submenu').show();
    $(this).children('.mainmenu-submenu').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).children('.mainmenu-arrow').toggleClass('mainmenu-rotate');
    $(this).siblings('.mainmenu-submenu-sub').slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).siblings('.mainmenu-submenu-sub-sub').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.megamenu').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.megamenu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

You first need to close all the already expanded accordion and then display the active one. Hope this helps.

Comment: King size: it is working in main sub links open, but second and third level menu is not expand.

Comment: First and second level not close when is open. But 3rd are working fine

Comment: Let me understand. When the first level menu is expanded, all other siblings of the parent of that menu should be collapsed. When second level menu is expanded, what should happen to the siblings of the parent of that menu?